# Firebase: avoiding database contention: instead of transaction, using update on a unique field in single doc

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

Been creeping towards facing the issue of 60w/doc/sec in my app. Did all the collection and document separation strategies I could think of. My unavoidable bottleneck are 'votes' on users posts, held in one document per post.

Uptil now I've been using transactions to populate a votes map with unique user identifiers.

My question is: instead of using transactions to set the UserID votes map, can I just use:

```
db.[databasePath].update({'votes.${UserID}': true});
```

Vote map structure:

```
votes = {
  'user1': false,
  'user2': true,
  'user3': false,
  ...
}
```

If I don't care what others are doing to the document, and I'm using a unique key in the map, can I trust this method to complete the update? Or is there a possibility that with many update calls coming in that some votes could be lost?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not bypass the limit of 1 write per second per document. Even if you are using different keys in your `votes` object, you are still writing to the same document.

One solution would be to write one document per voting user in a sub collection of the main document (i.e. the one representing the subject of the vote). This way you write to **different** docs and you are note constrained by the 1 write per second limit anymore.

If you need to have the total number of votes (in addition to the nbr of votes per user), you could use a Cloud Function which writes to a [distributed counter](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/counters) within a transaction. This CF would be triggered for any creation of a voting doc. You will need to create a distributed counter per main document.

Similarly, if you need to know the total votes per user (across main documents), just update another set of distributed counters.

Comment: oh my... for some reason I was running under the impression that the limit was 60 writes per document per second. I will certainly have to implement your method. Thank you.

Comment: Glad I could help you! You may upvote my answer if you think it was helpful. thanks!

Comment: Out of curiosity. Does listDocuments() count as one document read? If so, I could store votes1 and votes2 in two subcollections and just use listDocuments to get the count? or does listDocuments not scale well with 2000+ documents? I can't seem to find details on the function specifically

Comment: What is exactly `listDocuments()`? I'm mainly focusing on the JavaScript SDK and I am not sure what is `listDocuments()`.

Comment: listDocuments() returns a list of all document references under a subcollection. Digging through documentation and still can't determine how many reads it costs. 
https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/CollectionReference.html#listDocuments

Comment: Oh yes, from the Node.js SDK! AFAIK, it will cost one document read per `DocumentReference` returned.

Comment: I have confirmed from another source on SO that the read cost is one. I'm trying to determine now if the function scales well... I'm hoping firebase has some magic index of the documents at the collection level. Otherwise, if listDocuments() is computed each time, I need to figure out how it is computed under the hood.

Comment: That being said, the Shards strategy is really cool. However, the listDocuments method would be epic. effectively removing the write bottleneck for only 3x the document read cost.

Comment: For the indexing, watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ofux_4c94FI

Comment: Note that in the answers and comments of your other question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62007048/firebase-cloud-firestore-listdocuments-doc-read-cost-1-or-n-possible-alterna) Frank and Doug actually indicate that this will not be a "magic solution": if you want to use `listDocuments()` for counting the docs, you will pay one read per document in the collection. Like if you would do a simple `collection(...).get()`.

Comment: Ah, yes I reread everything and misread one answer as 1 read per listDocuments call. Guess I was too excited to think otherwise. Back to the shards!