# Firebase: Cloud Firestore: listDocuments: doc read cost 1 or N? Possible alternative to Distributed Counter?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Building a social media app and confronting the 1write/doc/sec limit. Consequently, keeping vote data in the post document will not work at scale. I have read into "Distributed Counters", but the document read/write cost scales linearly. I have been exploring the firebase functions available and am interested in "listDocuments()", which return a List of DocumentReference's

Unfortunately, digging through the documentation I cannot determine if listDocument read cost is 1 or 1/doc in the collection.

My plan is to have two subcollections per post, vote1/vote2. This removes the write bottleneck at scale. To retrieve the vote count I would like to use the length of listDocuments() on each subcollection.

I know firebase has some neat indexing tricks, but I am also curious if this is an inefficient operation on the database. i.e. will the user notice a delay when retrieving the counts?

Comment: Personally, I would not assume there is anything scalable about the use of listDocuments.

Comment: That was my fear. I was hoping Firestore had some magic indexed at collections to provide the list. @DougStevenson, do you have an idea of size where listDocuments would start to be inefficient? Or where I could find more detailed documentation for under the hood operation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Unfortunately, digging through the documentation I cannot determine if listDocument read cost is 1 or 1/doc in the collection.

Calling the `listDocuments` API cost one <kbd>document read</kbd> per document that is returned by it.

Comment: As per Dougs comment on the question, I am curious how well this scales for collections with 1000+ documents. I would hope Firestore keeps this indexed somehow at the collection level.

Comment: Firestore will never perform any query that doesn't use an index.  The point is that you probably shouldn't rely on it as a "cheap" way to get a document count.

Comment: Just reread everything and realized I misunderstood "API cost one document read per document that is returned by it." as one read per listDocuments call. I will switch back to Distributed Counters. Thanks again.

Comment: Do you know if there's a piece of documentation that states that explicitly? It makes sense and everything, but... I've searched for a while, and I've found nothing that contradicts this statement, but also nothing that _directly_ supports it.

Comment: @puff - it says one document read - https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing#other-queries

Comment: That section seems to specifically talk about listing collections, not document reads. Since `listDocuments` returns the full documents (and thus needs to read them), it charges one document read for each document that it reads.

Comment: Ok, what about with `select()` which returns only selected fields? Is it possible to get just the document ids and incur just one read?

Comment: No, that's not possible

Comment: Ok, the docs then probably need to be updated to clarify. Thanks

Comment: @Jonathan if you check my answer on this post, you'll see the exact documentation. The best option is to setup a listener on the preferred collection and cache the results if not already cached by the api implementation.

Comment: @Yuki - thanks, was just curious about the charges... I guess a collection id is a collection name. Docs are just misleading

Answer (score 0):

Because there is some confusion around the read costs, especially with the listDocuments() function, i want to answer this question in more detail.
The answer of @Frank van Puffelen is correct, you'll get charged per returned document.

The listDocuments() method: Reading the parameter description allready hints that the documents get read.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1/projects.databases.documents/listDocuments

The return value: It stands out that you'll get an array of documents, not of their references.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1/ListDocumentsResponse

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48903472/firestore-request-for-a-list-of-collection-ids